# Conceptual (homological) interpretation of a theorem about flat modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, soft-question, homological-algebra, flatness

I just learned the following beautiful result about flat modules from J. S. Milne's book *Étale Cohomology*:

> Lemma 2.10(b'): Let $M$ be any flat $A$-module. If
> $$\sum_i a_ix_i=0,$$
> $a_i\in A$, $x_i\in M$, then there are equations
> $$x_i = \sum_j a_{ij}x_j'$$
> with $x_j'\in M$, $a_{ij}\in A$, such that
> $$\sum_i a_ia_{ij} = 0$$
> for all $j$.

It is stated under the hypothesis that $A$ is a commutative, noetherian ring, but as far as I can tell, the proof does not use noetherianity. (Actually I am not sure it even uses commutativity, but I will leave that matter alone for the purposes of this question.)

The proof given in Milne is essentially computational. However, the result struck me as almost a statement that something is exact (I'll make this precise in a moment), and of course flatness is all about exactness, so I wondered, **is there a conceptual argument, or at least some reasonably satisfying conceptual handwaving, that gives us the claimed result in terms of an assertion that something is exact, or some (co)homology vanishes, in a way that is straightforwardly connected to $M$'s flatness?**

(I'm using the soft-question tag because, while there could easily be a fully precise answer [which would be best possible], I will probably be happy with what I'm calling "satisfying conceptual handwaving," and what I mean by "straightforwardly" isn't precise either. Apologies in advance about this vagueness.)

Here is what I mean when I say the result struck me as "almost a statement that something is exact". The tuple $(a_i)_{i=1,\dots,r}$ defines a map $\varphi: M^r\rightarrow M$ by

$$(y_i)_{i=1,\dots,r} \mapsto \sum_i a_iy_i.$$

If $A$ is commutative, this is a map of $A$-modules. Then the equation

$$\sum_i a_ix_i=0$$

asserts that $(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in M^r$ lies in the kernel of this map. Similarly, the matrix $(a_{ij})$ defines a map $\psi: M^s\rightarrow M^r$ by

$$(y'_j)_{j=1,\dots,s}\mapsto \left(\sum_j a_{ij}y'_j\right)_{i=1,\dots,r},$$

whereupon the equations

$$\sum_i a_ia_{ij} = 0$$

assert that the composed map $\psi\circ\varphi = 0$, and the equations

$$x_i = \sum_j a_{ij}x_j'$$

assert that $(x_1,\dots,x_r)$ lies in the image of $\psi$. Thus the lemma "comes close" to asserting that we have a complex $M^s\xrightarrow{\psi} M^r \xrightarrow{\varphi} M$ which is exact in the middle.

It is not *actually* asserting this because the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is allowed to depend on the tuple $(x_i)$ (and the proof indeed requires the data of the $(x_i)$ for the construction of the $(a_{ij})$). So the real statement is: given an $A$-linear map $\varphi: M^r\rightarrow M$ defined by a tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$, *and given an element $(x_1,\dots,x_r)$ of the kernel of this map*, there is an $A$-linear map $\varphi: M^s\rightarrow M^r$ defined by a matrix $(a_{ij})$, such that $M^s\rightarrow M^r\rightarrow M$ forms a complex and the particular given $(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in M^r$ lies in the image of $\psi$. There is no assertion that the entire kernel of $\varphi$ is exhausted by the image of $\psi$.

Nonetheless, these musings are sufficiently suggestive to me that I wanted to ask here: **can you explain Milne's Lemma 2.10(b') in terms of the exactness of something, or the vanishing of some homology or cohomology, in a way that is evidently linked to $M$'s flatness over $A$?**

Comment: This may or may not help: Please check that the lemma is (or is not) equivalent to the "equational condition" given here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module#Characterizations_of_flatness). Of course flatness is equivalent to the Tor functor being exact, which means that some (co)homologies vanish, and this might be equivalent to the lemma (by the wikipedia article). I recall having seen a list of equivalent conditions for flatness somewhere, but I can't find it now, and it linked all these conditions in a nice way.

Comment: This reminds me of a criterion involving Fitting ideals, see Stacks Project [Tag 07ZD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ZD).

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph - it does appear equivalent to the "equational condition." The "paraphrase" given there, "[$A$]-linear relations that hold in $M$ stem from linear relations that hold in [$A$]," is giving me some insight about it.

By "Tor being exact" I assume you mean "Tensor being exact" or maybe "Tor vanishing"?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Yes, good catch! "Tor" is too close to "tensor" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you already know this and are looking for something more conceptual, but here's a way to connect this statement to a more homologically flavoured one.

A module $M$ over some commutative ring $R$ is flat precisely if $\mathbf{Tor}_1^R(R/I,M)$ vanishes for all finitely generated ideals $I \subset R$.

A handwavy proof: $M$ is flat if $\mathbf{Tor}_1^R(N,M)$ vanishes for all $N$. By cocontinuity using that every module is the colimit of its finitely generated submodules, flatness is equivalent to the vanishing of $\mathbf{Tor}_1^R(N,M)$ for all $N$ finitely generated. Such a module sits in a filtration with cyclic quotients and allows us to assume $N$ to be cyclic, hence of the form $R/I$. "$\square$"

Moreover, in the same proposition it is shown that $M$ is flat if for any finitely generated ideal $I \subset R$ tensoring the inclusion gives an injective map $I \otimes M \to M$. This is a matter of using the aforementioned equivalence and the long exact sequence for $\mathbf{Tor}$ applied to the short exact sequence

$$
0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0.
$$

Indeed, since $\mathbf{Tor}_1^R(R,M) = 0$ we have

$$
0 \to \mathbf{Tor}_1^R(R/I,M) \to I \otimes M \to R \otimes M \simeq M
$$
so the vanishing of $\mathbf{Tor}$ is exactly characterized the injectivity of $I \otimes M \to M$.

Therefore, flatness is intrinsically related to all the kernels of inclusion-induced maps $\langle a_1, \ldots, a_n\rangle \otimes M \to M$. Concretely, for $M$ to be flat we need that whenever

$$
\sum_{i}b_i a_i m_i = 0
$$
in $M$,
$$
\sum_{i} b_i a_i \otimes m_i = 0
$$
in $\langle a_1, \ldots, a_n\rangle \otimes M$. This already looks connected to the equational criterion, and in fact the connection comes from the following lemma on zero elements of certain tensor products,

> **Lemma.** *Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $M, N$ two $R$-modules and $\{n_i\}_{i \in I}$ a finite generating set for $N$. Given $\{m_i\}_i \subset M$, we have $\sum_i m_i \otimes n_i = 0$ if and only if there exists a finite set $J$ and elements $r_{ij} \in R, \widetilde{m}_j \in M$ such that*
> $$
> \sum_{j} r_{ij}\widetilde{m}_j = m_i, \quad \sum_{i \in I}r_{ij}n_i = 0 \quad (i \in I, j \in J).
> $$

All of this can be found in section $6.3$ of Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*.

Comment: Thank you for this (+1). I have not had time to digest it yet but look forward to doing so soon.

Comment: I will work through your argument in comments. I am indeed finding it a bit more conceptual than Milne's argument (in fairness, perhaps because I've now been thinking about all this for a few days.) We suppose we have $\sum a_i x_i=0$ in $M$, a flat module over a ring $A$. Let $I=\langle a_1,\dots,a_r\rangle$ be the ideal generated by the $a_i$'s in $A$. By flatness, $I\otimes M \rightarrow M$ is injective. Since $\sum a_ix_i=0$ in $M$, this means $\sum a_i\otimes x_i$ in $I\otimes M$ is zero too. By the lemma at the end, this linear relation implies the existence of a family of (cont'd)

Comment: expressions for the $x_i$ in $M$, such that the coefficients can be pulled across the $\otimes$ to yield linear relations *in $I$*. This is exactly the content of Milne's Lemma 2.10(b'). Eisenbud's lemma makes sense to me as just an expression of the standard explicit construction of tensor products.

Comment: This is a different direction of thought than I was asking the question from, but maybe it is more to the point. I guess it's not so much that the maps $\varphi, \psi$ in the OP exist and satisfy $\varphi\circ\psi=0$ etc., so much as that they are defined by matrices over $A$. What I learned from @LetGBeTheGraph's comment on the OP is also shaping this thinking.